# CompileXaml failed unexpectedly

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

I`ve created a new project of a windows 8 application. I want to create it with c#/xaml. I'm creating project and than I press F5 and I get

> The "CompileXaml" task failed unexpectedly.
>   System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>   at Microsoft.Windows.UI.Xaml.Build.Tasks.CompileXaml.CheckForDesignTimeBuildMode()
>   at Microsoft.Windows.UI.Xaml.Build.Tasks.CompileXaml.Execute()
>   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
>   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.d__20.MoveNext()

I didn`t change anything. Same thing happens when I chose BlankTemplate, SplitTemplate, GridTemplate.

Dunno what to do

Comment: You have tried restarting Visual Studio, just in case? You are running Visual Studio 2012 RC on Windows Release Preview?

Comment: i was testing VS2011 Beta, VS2012 for Win8 Apps. Everywhere same thing. I`m now reinstalling VS2012 and I will install VS2012 Express For Windows 8. I`ve donwloaded it from MS site

Comment: I am having a similar (possibly related issue) in VS 2022 17.5.2 (been happing since before this).  For me, the message only appears *after* I restart VS.  Prior to the restart, I'm getting a ton of incorrect error messages of the type "Ambiguous reference between <name_of_property> and <name_of_property>" where the <name_of_property> is identical; i.e., it is the same property.  I've submitted a bug to https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Errors-persist-display-even-after-succes/10291403 but no joy yet.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. Tbh I`m not sure how I did this.

I've uninstalled all visual stuidos and downloaded latest version of Visual Studio 2012 RC from MS site. Installed it from scratch and it worked

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade your Visual Studio 2013 from Update 2 to Update 4. When you Build your project it gives and error about Hyper - V Network adapter. To Solve that, allow to change in Hyper -V Network Adapter settings by click on "Retry" button in prompt. ( You can also upgrade Window phone SDK to 8.1 for better experience. It is optional not necessary to solve this error.)