# window phone 7 error

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, compiler-errors, runtime-error

I have a project that worked fine but today i get this error... even when I creating new project i get same message... I can't understand what is the problem...

```
Error   1   The "CompileXaml" task failed unexpectedly.
System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Windows, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e' or one of its dependencies. Strong name validation failed. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8013141A)
File name: 'System.Windows, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e' ---> System.Security.SecurityException: Strong name validation failed. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8013141A)

The Zone of the assembly that failed was:
MyComputer
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadFrom(String assemblyFile, Evidence securityEvidence, Byte[] hashValue, AssemblyHashAlgorithm hashAlgorithm, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom(String assemblyFile)
   at Microsoft.Silverlight.Build.Tasks.CompileXaml.LoadSilverlightAssemblies(String[] frameworkPaths)
   at Microsoft.Silverlight.Build.Tasks.CompileXaml.GenerateCode(ITaskItem item, Boolean isApplication)
   at Microsoft.Silverlight.Build.Tasks.CompileXaml.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.ExecuteInstantiatedTask(ITaskExecutionHost taskExecutionHost, TaskLoggingContext taskLoggingContext, TaskHost taskHost, ItemBucket bucket, TaskExecutionMode howToExecuteTask, Boolean& taskResult)
```

Comment: It appears your missing System.Windows.dll which is part of the Windows Phone SDK I am sure.  This is where I would start.

Comment: Most probably you have to reinstall visual studio

Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11375343/compilexaml-failed-unexpectedly

Comment: I not missing `System.Windows.dll` I will reinstall it...

Comment: After re-installation it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best Answer of Carl Saldanha (read comments)

Need re-installation...