# "CompileXaml" task failed unexpectedly in Visual Studio while develop Xamarin project

Tags: visual-studio-2013, xamarin

I opened a Xamarin cross platform sample Project in Visual studio 2013 and When I build, it gives this error:-

[This question is also same but no one reply any answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11375343/compilexaml-failed-unexpectedly)

Error   2   The "CompileXaml" task failed unexpectedly.
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'XamlServicesWP, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'XamlServicesWP, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'

Server stack trace: 
   at Microsoft.Silverlight.Build.Tasks.CompileXaml.GenerateCode(ITaskItem item, Boolean isApplication)
   at Microsoft.Silverlight.Build.Tasks.CompileXaml.Execute()
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr md, Object[] args, Object server, Object[]& outArgs)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.d__20.MoveNext()

WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally , I got solution for this. I upgrade my Visual Studio from Update 2 to Update 4. When you Build your project it gives and error about Hyper - V Network adapter. To Solve that, allow to change in Hyper -V Network Adapter settings by click on "Retry" button in prompt. ( You can also upgrade Window phone SDK to 8.1 for better experience. It is optional not necessary to solve this error.)

Answer (score 0):

I worked around this problem by going back to Visual Studio 2019, rather than sticking with Visual Studio 2022. It seems 2022 still has a few issues.